# How to implement URL rewriting two rules with the same extension?

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ post-details.php?post_id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^post-year-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]+)\.html$ post-details-year.php?post_year=$1&post_month=$2  [L]
```

The first rule is working and giving me the correct output but the second one is not; it jumped to the first rule with "**post_details.php**" desired "**Post-details-year.php**".

Additionally when I change the file extension:

Example:

```
RewriteRule ^post-year-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]+)\.html$ post-details-year.php?post_year=$1&post_month=$2  [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^post-year-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]+)\.cgi$ post-details-year.php?post_year=$1&post_month=$2  [L]
```

Comment: `post-year-...html` is a valid rule for the first one (`p`, `o`, `s`, ... are all valid characters for the first character group).
Try putting the second rule first, it should work.

Comment: tankxz  yoavmatchulsky  Its Working now :)

But If I will put  3 rules then ? if this problem came up again ?

Comment: Please Clear My Confusion why it happened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the rewriting engine starts going over the your rules one by one until it find one that fits.

The problem was that your first rule was very powerful, and it catched URLs you didn't want it to.

When you try and access `post-year-123.html`, the first rule matches `post-year` to `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` part of the regex, and `123` to `([0-9]+)`, which then just redirects you according to the first rule.

If you switch them, and put the second rule first, it will first try to match it and will success, thus sending you to the place you want.

Comment: sure, no problem. just remember to select the answer :)